# rspec/capybara/selenium testing - downloading/visit external urls and checking for content type

Tags: testing, selenium, rspec, cross-domain, capybara

I understand that in order for capybara to visit external urls, the driver has to be one that supports that (such as selenium). But when selenium is used, I can no longer check for the content type via page.response_headers since that is not supported by the selenium driver. Is there any alternative to response_headers, or am I simply looking at the wrong set of tools?

Answer (score 0):

I use the `capybara-webkit` driver and I can confirm that `page.response_headers` works for external sites.